# How to add a image column in a database with other columns already inserted in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

SQL Server Management Studio

I made a system database called `ProjectXXX`. It contains a table called `dbo.VideoGames`.

Inside the database I declared 5 columns, one of them called `Images` with the data type `varbinary(MAX)` with allow nulls enabled.

The others are

```
Name
Price
ProductID
System
```

I have used the following statement from a thread in StackOverflow:

```
Insert Into [ProjectXXX].[dbo].[VideoGames] (Images)
   Select *
   from Openrowset (Bulk
       'C:\Users\DevLaDevine\Desktop\ImageDatabase\AssassinsCreedIX.jpg',
       Single_Blob) as Image
```

It affects 1 row which is a new row which can't be edited/modify.

I have 14 rows which it added a 15th row with the image information in it.

I want to be able to assign it to the first column and then run another statement to add a second image into the second row and over and over until all 14 rows have a image in it.

So it would like like this

```
Assassins Creed IX | 49.99 | 1 | PS4 | *Where the image info should go* |
```

Sorry for the lack of formatting as I am doing this on mobile at the time.

Comment: Your question is about MySQL or SQL-Server ?

Comment: SQL Server. I am trying to create a database. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would update a row with `ProductID = 1` (if there are several such rows, all of them will be updated) and set the value of the column `Images` to the JPG file.

```
UPDATE dbo.VideoGames
SET Images = 
(
SELECT
    BinData.BulkColumn
FROM
    OPENROWSET (BULK
    'C:\Users\DevLaDevine\Desktop\ImageDatabase\AssassinsCreedIX.jpg',
    SINGLE_BLOB) as BinData
)
WHERE [ProductID] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, that makes sense. I'm new to Databases and this helped me out so much.